# How to obtain if a CodeTypeRef is nullable or not

Tags: c#, t4, envdte

In a T4 template file I wrote some codes to generate a class based on the passed CodeTypeRef type. The generated class would have all the properties of the passed type with a minor difference : All properties should be nullable. For example assume I passed the following type :

```
public class MyClass
{
     int x {get;set;}
     string y {get;set;}
     Guid z {get;set;}
     byte[] m{get;set;}
     float? n{get;set;}
}
```

Now the generated class would be something like this :

```
public class MyClass
{
     int? x {get;set;}
     string y {get;set;}
     Guid? z {get;set;}
     byte[] m{get;set;}
     float? n{get;set;}
}
```

As you see just the **int x** and **Guid z** properties changed to nullable types.
What I have in T4 is :

```
  <# foreach(var prop in modelType.VisibleMembers().OfType<CodeProperty>()) { #>
  public  <#= prop.Type.AsString  #>  <#= prop.Name #>{ get; set; } 
  <# } #>
```

I don't know how to obtain if **prop.Type** can be nullable or not.
 NOTE : using **prop.Type.TypeKind** is helpful but not in all types.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Determine if the model's property is not nullable or is required (in MVCScaffolding T4 Template File)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821489/determine-if-the-models-property-is-not-nullable-or-is-required-in-mvcscaffold)