# Determine if the model's property is not nullable or is required (in MVCScaffolding T4 Template File)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, t4, scaffolding, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

**I want write a method to get Nullable State of a property in T4 Template file.**

I've written it in my TT files but in the T4 files it is different

```
bool IsRequired(object property) {
    bool result=false;

    ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?

    return result;
}
```

---

```
List<ModelProperty> GetEligibleProperties(EnvDTE.CodeType typeInfo, bool includeUnbindableProperties) {
    List<ModelProperty> results = new List<ModelProperty>();
    if (typeInfo != null) {
        foreach (var prop in typeInfo.VisibleMembers().OfType<EnvDTE.CodeProperty>()) {
            if (prop.IsReadable() && !prop.HasIndexParameters() && (includeUnbindableProperties || IsBindableType(prop.Type))) {
                results.Add(new ModelProperty {
                    Name = prop.Name,
                    ValueExpression = "Model." + prop.Name,
                    Type = prop.Type,
                    IsPrimaryKey = Model.PrimaryKeyName == prop.Name,
                    IsForeignKey = ParentRelations.Any(x => x.RelationProperty == prop),
                    IsReadOnly = !prop.IsWriteable(),

                    // I Added this >>
                    IsRequired = IsRequired(prop)
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

How do it???

Answer (score 3):

Struggeling with the same question one year later I detected your question. I don´t think it´s possible in an uncomplicated way, because you have to transfer the CodeTypeRef to a Systemtype. This is a nice hack, that works fine with models and mvcscaffolding:

```
bool IsNullable(EnvDTE.CodeTypeRef propType) {
  return propType.AsFullName.Contains(".Nullable<");
}
```

You should call this function in this way:

```
               // I Added this >>
               // IsRequired = IsRequired(prop)
                IsRequired = !IsNullable(prop.Type);
            });
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be IsRequired = !IsNullable(prop.Type)

Comment: @Ken Mc: yes, exactly, I changed my post

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about it being called from a T4 template, is there?  See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374651/how-to-check-if-an-object-is-nullable)

I personally like Mike Jones's answer, reproduced here for convenience.

```
public static bool IsObjectNullable<T>(T obj)
{
  // If the parameter-Type is a reference type, or if the parameter is null, then the object is     always nullable
  if (!typeof(T).IsValueType || obj == null)
    return true;

  // Since the object passed is a ValueType, and it is not null, it cannot be a nullable object
  return false; 
}

public static bool IsObjectNullable<T>(T? obj) where T : struct
{
  // Always return true, since the object-type passed is guaranteed by the compiler to always be nullable
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with MvcScaffolding since you don't have any objects, just the property metadata.
Since you get System.Int32 as TypeName for both a non-nullable and nullable integer, you can't use the TypeName either.